# How do I sort tuples by given element in Julia?

Tags: sorting, tuples, julia

If I have a list/array of tuples like this: `[(15, 36, 39), (9, 40, 41)]`

How do I sort these by the first element? By the last element? By their sum?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
x=[(15, 36, 39), (9, 40, 41)]
sort(x, by=x->x[1])
sort(x, by=x->x[end])
sort(x, by=sum)
```

This answer your questions?

Comment: You could also write `first` / `last` instead of `x->x[1]` / `x->x[end]`, depending on what you think looks nicer

Comment: Also as of 1.5, you can write x[begin]